# Zsh how to access a hard-coded array whose name is passed in as a user argument?

Tags: linux, zsh

I am attempting to write a small program called `systemtheme` that exports color hex codes as environment variables to theme other programs. I have hard-coded two themes in the script, onedark and dracula, and I would like to call the script like `systemtheme onedark`. Here is the working script that does *not* use user input:

```
 #! /usr/bin/env zsh
  
 onedark=('#282c34' '#e06c75' '#98c379' ... )
 dracula=('#282a36' '#ff5555' '#50fa7b' ... )

 color_names=('BACKGROUND' 'RED' 'GREEN' 'YELLOW' ... )

 export SYSTEM_THEME="onedark"
 export TRANSPARENT="#00000000"

 for (( i = 1; i <= 17; i++ )); do
     export $color_names[i]=$onedark[$i]
 done
```

This can be verified because I call those values in other programs, and I can check in the terminal with

```
> print $RED
#e06c75
```

I would like to replace the `export` lines with something like

```
 export SYSTEM_THEME="$1"
 export TRANSPARENT="#00000000"

 for (( i = 1; i <= 17; i++ )); do
     export $color_names[i]=$1[$i]
 done
```

but I am running into a lot of trouble. I think there is a way, but I am new to zsh and I'm not too sure the difference between all the ' " $() ${} '${}' ... operations in zsh. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Indirect parameter expansion is done using the `P` parameter expansion flag.

```
export $color_names[i]=${(P)1[$i]}
```

This allows the value of `$1` to be used as the name of the parameter to expand.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much for the info and quick response. That did it for me. I learned something new about zsh today! ^_^